# CSS issue in SAFARI: OTP input field

Tags: html, css, one-time-password

I have implemented an HTML input field for OTP verification, it runs absolutely fine in chrome but when I open it in SAFARI it shows an extra input in the right-hand side.

Here is the running code: [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/xohasa/edit?html,css,js,output)

HTML code:

```
<div id="otp-holder">
  <div id="otp-content">
    <input id="otp-input" type="tel" maxlength="6" pattern="\d{6}" autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
#otp-input {
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  letter-spacing: 24px;
  border: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #167ffc 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 33px 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position-x: 19px;
  width: 220px;
  min-width: 220px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#otp-content {
  left: 0;
  position: sticky;
}

#otp-holder {
  width: 190px;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

Please have a look at the screenshot of jsbin when open it in SAFARI
[image]

Here you can see I started by typing 1,2...6 and at last there 1 extra underline and 1st input hides when I reach last.

Comment: Do you mean it looks like another one, due to the 23px letter-spacing?

Comment: It should show 6 input fields but in safari it shows 1 extra at last

Comment: If you mean 6 "underlines", this is what safari v12.0 displays. What version of safari do you have this issue?

Comment: I have tested your jsBin in `7.1, 8, 9.1, 10.1, 11.1 and 12` of safari for mac and it all shows only 6 underlines.

Comment: I am using v12 and it is there and have tested with other mac as well.
I am attaching a screenshot to make it more clear

Answer (score -1):

Few minor upadtes to your code and it works fine, please have a look at the below working snippet.

```css
#otp-holder {
  width: 190px;
  overflow: hidden
}
#otp-content {
  left: 0;
  position: sticky;
}
#otp-input {
  padding: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 27px;
  border: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #167ffc 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 33px 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position-x: 19px;
  width: 100%; /* set width matching container width */
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="otp-holder">
  <div id="otp-content">
    <input id="otp-input" type="tel" maxlength="6" pattern="\d{6}" autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working, not I can see more than 1 extra underlines (around 4)